# Objective C casting Class structure pointer to a concrete class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, casting, static-methods

In Objective C, there's a Class structure which acts as a pointer to any class implementations you have. In Objective C, it's defined as:

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
```

I'm trying to have a array of Classes and I'm trying to iterate through the Class array and perform static functions. Some sample code below:

```
//Each class is subclassed from the same abstract class with a function specialStaticFunction
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:Class1, Class2, Class3];

for(Class tempClass in array)
    [tempClass specialStaticFunction];
}
```

When running that code, I get warning because not every Class has a function called specialStaticFunction. So I want to know how to cast a Class or how else someone might circumvent this warning.

Comment: I don't think that's actually the error you're getting. It's fine it send messages that not every class responds to. What is the actual error?

Comment: "I get warning because not every Class has a function called specialStaticFunction" Nope. The compiler does not check messages sent to type `Class`.

Comment: Also, your code is wrong, because the arguments to `initWithObjects:` must be terminated with `nil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `id` instead of `Class` here

```
for(id tempClass in array)
```

This should remove the warnings from the compiler, but you still need to ensure each object implements that method otherwise your app will crash.

Comment: Give a further check using `isKindOfClass`